# Permanently blacklist linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have pcspkr in blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/pcspkr.conf`. However, I can manually load the module using modprobe.

I'm guessing, some other component will be able to do the same via *module alias* mechanism. Is there a way to permanently block automatic loading of a specific kernel module?

My use case is that I want to experiment with an alternative driver than the one provided in-tree. For this, I do not want the system's default driver showing up. I do not want to delete the golden driver provided by the kernel and screw up either.

What options do I have ?

Comment: Could you temporarily rename/move the default driver? That way you can easily restore it, but it wont be loaded while you are testing.

Comment: That seems to be the only option I suppose ;)